# Which performance measure for unbalanced binary classification without an 'active' class?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation

My datasets have two classes A and B. The classes should be treated equally (there is no "active/inactive"). The datasets are unbalanced, sometimes A is more frequent, sometimes B is more frequent. Which performance measure should I use?

Accuracy makes no sense on unbalanced datasets. If I get it right, F-measure and AUC assume that there is a active class: F-measure ignores true negatives as it is the harmonic mean of precision and recall. AUC ignores true negatives and false negatives.

So what performance measure should I use?
Is AUC(active=A) + AUC(active=B) / 2 a valid option?

**CORRECTION:**

Apparently, I missunderstood how AUC works. It does NOT ignore true negatives and false negatives. The ROC curves look different depending on which class is considered the active one, but AUC(active=A) = AUC(active=B).

Comment: Do you have a cost function ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. My instances have equal weights. My classifier gives a probability with each prediction. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Your instances may have equal weights, do your errors have equal weights ?  If they do, then accuracy is a valid measure of performance.

Comment: Each error has equal weight. How does this make accuracy valid? Lets assume I would like to compare validation results on two datasets, one is largely unbalanced, one is not?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, the accuracy on one dataset, say breast cancer prediction, and the accuracy on another dataset, say horse racing, are related in what way? Or are you saying you are sampling the same underlying distribution and the samples have varying ratios of class A and B?

Comment: @image_doctor
Don't want to make it too complicated for now, I think my last question was miss-leading. Lets consider only a single unbalanced dataset:
How can accuracy be useful here? Predicting only the majority class might give a higher accuracy than a better classifier that predicts some of the minority instances right.

Comment: This is where the cost function for errors comes in. If your errors have EQUAL weights then the classifier that predicts the majority class in that case is the more accurate classifier. If the errors do not have equal weights, then you should weight the errors appropriately using a suitable cost function :)

Comment: Ah, understand, if I have 80% As and 20% Bs, I'll weight the As with 0.2 and the Bs with 0.8, right? Makes sense.
And without a cost function?

Comment: The cost function would normally be derived from the application domain dependent on how "expensive" making false positive and false negative errors are. In the example you give, you are declaring an error in mislabeling a B instance to be four times as damaging as mislabeling  an instance of A. What goal are you trying to achieve ?  Other techniques are over sampling the minority class, under sampling the majority class, adding noise to the to minority class instances to make new samples, estimating the distribution of the minority class and sampling from that.

Comment: My goal is simply to have a method that is invariant to the distribution of my class variables. I think weighting the errors differently, or changing my datasets is not a good option. But I've done some research about AUC and apparently I got it wrong, I will correct my questions accordingly.

Comment: When you say a method invariant to the class distribution ... learning algorithms are explicitly dependent on the class distribution. If your samples have large variations in distribution, perhaps you could consider aggregating samples or using a sample technique that balanced the classes.  But classifiers trained this way will show poorer performance on highly unbalanced samples. Otherwise you might want to consider algorithms which are more tolerant to sample variation, or if your samples are bimodal, train a separate classifier for each mode.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)

$$MCC = \frac{TP \cdot TN - FP \cdot FN}{\sqrt{ (TP + FP)(TP + FN)(TN + FP)(TN + FN) }}$$

I have seen it pretty often as performance metrix in classification of SNPs dataset. Have a look at this [link](http://www.biostars.org/p/61345/) as well, they discuss the difference between AUC and MCC

Otherwise you can just compute an average accuracy (average error rate), I have seen people using it in multiclass problems as well.

$$AAcc = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{TP}{TP + FN} + \frac{TN}{TN + FP} \bigg) $$

Usually it is used in authentication systems under the form of Half Total Error Rate. E.g. [here](http://www.isca-speech.org/archive_open/archive_papers/odyssey_04/ody4_237.pdf) they provided a statistical test for that.